# how can I turn config ini file into system environment in bash?

Tags: bash

I have config files like below

```
# this is sample config file like config.ini
APP_HOME=/usr/local/bin
DATABASE_DIR=/usr/local/database
```

Normally in order to be access as system environment, it shall use `export` in front

```
# this is sample config file like config.rc
export APP_HOME=/usr/local/bin
export DATABASE_DIR=/usr/local/database
```

And I can

```
$ source config.rc
$ echo "APP_HOME is $APP_HOME"
APP_HOME is /usr/local/bin
```

Now Which is the easiest way one line command to turn config file `config.ini` into system environment ? could be combine with `sed`/`awk` command

Comment: You don't need `export` which is only needed for *subsequently executed commands*. If you `source config.rc` variables will be available in your current shell even without `export`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can tell the shell to automatically export variables, **if** you really do need this to be exported.

```
set -a               # turn on automatic export
source config.ini    # execute all commands in the file
set +a               # turn off automatic export
```

Comment: This is probably the cleanest solution to a problem that might not even exist :-)

Comment: coool, this is what I want.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/^/export /g' config.ini > config.sh && source config.sh
```

The *sed* command add 'export ' to the beginning for each line of config.ini and then redirect the output to config.sh, then the *source* shell builtin read and execute the exports in the current shell environment.

Comment: Some explanation would be useful, rather than simply posting code.

Comment: Why create a temporary file at all? `source <(sed 's/^/export /')` would have the same effect without it.

Answer (score 0):

To export the variables in that file after you `source` if:

```
export $(grep -oP '^\s*\K[_[:alpha:]]\w+(?==)' config.ini)
```

Answer (score -1):

one line:
 `cat 1.ini | awk '{print "export "$0}'`